# Facebook does not request web-site when scraping URL for the first time

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, nginx

I have an error when trying to share http://pixride.com/pictures/test/10000:

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.
```

When I put this link in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/, FB does not even fire a request to web-site. When I click "Fetch new scrape information" or "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL", then FB makes a request and everything works fine. I turned off GZip at nginx, put only A-records in DNS, return only static content. What else should I tune?

Comment: When you first load the URL in the debug tool it shows Facebook's existing cache for that URL - only when you explicitly re-request the metadata does it send a request - does that answer your question or is there another issue with what Facebook is seeing?

Comment: fb.com rejects to show image when sharing that is specified in og:image meta tag. What else is required to share it?

Comment: What is the reason provided by the debugger for why the image is not shown? is that reason accurate? have you tried adding a parameter to the image URL (eg. `?v=`1) in case Facebook cached an old copy of the image, an error when trying to retrieve it previously, etc?

Comment: "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped." with no details. You are welcome to try yourself.

Comment: Are you accidentally putting the ':' character in, too? With the ':' at the end i see the error you mentioned, otherwise it works OK for me [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/G2fsTUC.png)

Comment: You seemed fetched new scrape information. Try another id for test, say, http://pixride.com/pictures/test/100100 while sharing on facebook.com. You should see no image information for post. Why?